# How to use NER and POS for model input?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am building a model for contract information extraction, where NER and POS could serve relevant information. I am trying with Keras (and XGBoost). My question would be what are the techniques to use all of this information (the actual text, NER, POS) for my model input which is currently using only text. Could not find anything about it yet.